# Django: Form class not working?

Tags: jquery, python, django

Because of the small scale of a website I'm creating, I decided to skip JSON and just create an ajax page which returned actual html or single words saying what to do. There seems to be some error in the code since at `new_user_pass = new_user(request.POST)` the server suddenly returns `500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)` The website checks if the user has loged in before, and then makes a decision: if they have, redirect to the home page after creating a session (yet to be coded). If they have not: Return a word that tells JQuery to ask them for additional information.  If there is an error somewhere, it should get to the end of the file where it returns errors (yet to be completely coded).

This is the forms.py file:

```
class log_in(forms.Form):
    username = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.PasswordInput()

class new_user(forms.Form):
    username = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.PasswordInput()
    password2 = forms.PasswordInput()
    pen_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
```

The views.py file:

```
def user_log_in(request):
    #add stuff for ajax request
    user_pass = log_in(request.POST)
    er = []
    if user_pass.is_valid():
        cleaned_info = user_pass.cleaned_data
        user_object = User.objects.filter(email = cleaned_info['username'])
        if user_object.exists():
            #create session
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
        else:
            new_user_pass = new_user(request.POST)#where bug is
            cleaned_info = new_user_pass.cleaned_data
            if new_user_pass.is_valid():
                if cleaned_info['password'] == cleaned_info['password2']:
                    new_user = User(activated = 0, email = cleaned_info['username'], pen_name = cleaned_info['pen_name'], password = cleaned_info['password'])
                    new_user.save()
                    msg = ""
                    if send_mail('Activate', msg, '*******', [cleaned_info['username']], fail_silently=False):
                        return HttpResponse('e_act')
                    else:
                        er.append("Error Sending Email")
                else:
                    er.append('Passwords are not the same')
            elif cleaned_info['TN']:
                for e in new_user_pass.errors:
                    er.append(e)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('n_usr')
    return HttpResponse('SOS')
```

And, though I don't think the error is here, the Jquery function:
n_usr = false;

```
function log_in () {
    //add code to check if it's the wrong usr, pass, correct, or if they've never logged in before.
    //code to reveal section
```

Edit: Django gived the error `new_user' referenced before assignment`

Comment: What does the Django error page say? You can see it in Firebug/Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: @DanielRoseman There is a lot of info, but what seems to some up the problem is "local variable 'new_user' referenced before assignment"

Comment: Rename one of 'new_user' names. If you init new_user farther in a function you can't use it as external name for another object in the function.

Comment: @sergzach Sorry, could you be more clear. What names? Am I using it as an external name?

Comment: See my answer please. You have mentioned the error associated with the new_user name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next fragment is wrong:

```
def new_user():
    print "in new_user"

def f():
    new_user()
    if True:
        new_user = 23
        print "new_user"

f()
```

You can't call new_user() because compiler thinks that it is in the scope of the f() because of the farther initialization of new_user.

You use new_user as two different things - as a constructor of the form

```
new_user(request.POST)
```

and as a User instance:

```
new_user = User(activated = 0, email = cleaned_info['username'], pen_name = cleaned_info['pen_name'], password = cleaned_info['password'])
```

It is also not good in terms of programming style - to use one name for absolutely different variables.

For example, you can use another name for the local variable and it must be OK:

```
new_user_inst = User(activated = 0, email = cleaned_info['username'], pen_name = cleaned_info['pen_name'], password = cleaned_info['password'])
...
```

Comment: @Mike G: I'm happy you've accepted this answer, but *please* address the point about your new User class where you are storing passwords in plain text. Please, please don't do this. Django goes to great lengths to do this right, don't undo all their good work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just changed it to use the User class that django creates.

Comment: @sergzach For some reason now it says "'new_user' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'"

Comment: @MikeG It indeed doesn't have cleaned_data unless you call is_valid(). Could you please update your answer and show me the code near the line where a call stack begins (near the line which cause the problem)? You can also check if new_user is of Form subtype. Output: print "type={0}".format( type( new_user ) )

Comment: @MikeG Yes, there is a mistake: call that 'cleaned_info = new_user_pass.cleaned_data' after this 'if new_user_pass.is_valid():'. So, it's not necessary to update your answer.

Comment: @sergzach Sorry, but what exactly should I change. What do mean by "call that"

Comment: @MikeG Use new_user_pass.cleaned_data after you call 'new_user_pass.is_valid()', because before 'is_valid()' your data is not 'clean' and 'new_user_pass' has not the attribute 'cleaned_data'. Place the line with 'cleaned_data' after the line with 'is_valid()'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14644/discussion-between-mike-g-and-sergzach)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't imported the `new_user` form into your view.

And I **do** hope that you haven't created your own User class, in which you are storing passwords in plain text. That would be bad.